# Laptop screen goes white

Tags: laptop-display

My laptop screen goes white if I push the screen little behind. It comes back to normal if I pull the screen little forward. What would be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

The connection for the LCD inside your laptop is lose or tear up. So when you move it, it loosens up and disconnects a bit but it then turned back on because it is glued and fixated in that position. You need to get that cable replaced. You can either do it yourself or take it to a repair shop.